# How to get this element and click on it with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Trying to make my bot click on a submit button.

```
<div class="usertext-buttons">
<button type="submit" onclick="" class="save">save</button>
<button type="button" onclick="return cancel_usertext(this);" class="cancel" style="display:none">cancel</button>
<span class="status"></span></div>
```

I want to get the second row element with the `type="submit"`

`driver.find_element_by_xpath` doesn't work since the xpath is different for every post. What can I pull here that generally works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.save[type='submit'][onclick]").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='save' and text()='save'][@type='submit' and @onclick]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.save[type='submit'][onclick]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='save' and text()='save'][@type='submit' and @onclick]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.usertext-buttons > button[type=submit]').click()
```